# Powershell script to delete files under certain amount

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a powershell script that will delete any file that is under 4kb. I have the following code and it is deleting everything any help would be awesome!

```
$Dir = "C:\powershelldeletetest"

$SizeMax = 4

$Size = (Get-ChildItem $Dir| Measure-Object -property length -sum)  

$SizeKb="{0:N2}" -f ($size.sum / 1KB) + "KB" 

if ($sizeKb -le $sizeMax) { 

Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | Remove-Item –Force 

}
```

Comment: You're comparing a string (`$SizeKB`, which has *KB* at the end) with a number (`$sizeMax`). How would that work? How would `"4KB"` ever equal `4`? Try `$sizeMin = 4096` (because you want the minimum file sizes to be 4K or larger), remove the whole `$sizeKB` stuff, and use `if ($Size -le $sizeMin)` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ken White said, your condition ($sizeKb -le $sizeMax) has an error.

Otherwise, wouldn't you just :

1. List the files from a folder
2. Add a condition where it's length is less than 4096 bytes
3. Delete the selected item

ie.

```
Get-ChildItem -File | where length -le 4096| Remove-Item
```

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
$Dir = "C:\Downloads"

Get-ChildItem $Dir -Recurse -File | where-object {$_.Length -le 4kb } | Remove-Item –Force
```